# How to fetch all id from table after multiple insertion on a table

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am passing datatable as input parameter to a stored procedure. I have created custom type for it.
Here is my stored procedure:

```
 INSERT INTO Employee
                ([Name],[Lname],[Code])
    SELECT [Name],[Lname],@Code
    FROM   @tblEmp A
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   Employee B
                       inner join Contactdetail c
                       on cid = B.cid
                       WHERE  B.[Name] = A.[Name]
                              AND B.[Lname] = A.[Lname]
                              AND C.[mobno] = A.[mobno])
```

Here I fetching record from datatable and inserting into Employee table. Datatable contain Name,Lname and mobileno. I want to check combination of Name,Lname and mobileno.If combination of it present in Employee table,pls don't insert record([Name], [Lname], @Code ) in Employee.Else Insert.After inserting record from Employee,I want id of all inserted record.Scope_identity give last identity of table.I want all id,which are newly inserted into table because in same sp,I want to do further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause like:

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs table(EmployeeID int);

INSERT INTO Employee
                ([Name],[Lname],[Code])
             --
             OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
             INTO @InsertedIDs 
             --
    SELECT [Name],[Lname],@Code
    FROM   @tblEmp A
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   Employee B
                       inner join Contactdetail c
                       on cid = B.cid
                       WHERE  B.[Name] = A.[Name]
                              AND B.[Lname] = A.[Lname]
                              AND C.[mobno] = A.[mobno])
```

<kbd>[[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/NOTLJ86932)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can this with a [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement. (Could be there is a mistake in this query, but its just so you get the idea behind it...)

```
MERGE INTO Employee AS Target
USING (SELECT B.[Name], B.[Lname], C.[mobno]
        FROM  Employee B
        inner join Contactdetail c
        on cid = B.cid ) AS source (Name, Lname, mobno)
ON   Target.[Name] = Source.[Name]
 AND Target.[Lname] = Source.[Lname]
 AND Target.[mobno] = Source.[mobno]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (Name, Lname, code) VALUES (Name, Lname, @Code);
```